# DataGridView Selecting Row after Sort

Tags: winforms, sorting

I'm using an unbound DataGridView in a Windows form. A few columns are enabled for 'Automatic' sorting (click on column header to sort).

When no rows are selected (MyDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count == 0) and I click on the column header to sort, one row is selected. This row happens to be the first row added to the DGV when it was populated. **This is undesired behavior**; I wish to have no row selected which was not selected before the column was sorted.

Alternately - when I select a row by clicking on it, and then sort using the column header, that same row remains selected. **This is desired behavior**.

Furthermore, if I then unselect all rows programmatically using MyDataGridView.ClearSelection(), then do the sort, the previously selected row is now reselected. **This is undesired behavior**.

Each time a sort is performed (which causes the selection to change) the 'SelectionChanged' event fires. Unfortunately I am not able to discern the cause of the event . Was it due to my clicking on a row, or doing a sort?

This problem occurs even if I perform the sort programmatically.

Is there a way to ensure that only previously selected rows are selected after a sort? I have searched for answers and read a number of posts, but can't find anything that helps.

Comment: You can add a hidden Column that stores a progressive index of the Rows (or anything that can uniquely identify a Row), store these indexes (or references) when the `CellClick` event is related to a `RowIndex = -1`  (a Column Header click), then use the `Sorted` event to re-select all Rows that have a reference corresponding to what you have stored. You cannot use the `Index` of a DataGridViewRow, because, when you sort the grid, the Rows are unshared and lose their original index (if you store a DataGridViewRow reference, its Index will be `-1`, if you store Index values, wrong order)

Comment: Hi Jimi - Thanks for responding so quickly. In the meantime I came up with a very similar solution which uses MouseDown instead of CellClick. I just tried CellClick and it also works and is cleaner - so thanks for that.

Comment: My implementation is a little different - I use CellClick to set a flag if clicking a header cell. The flag is picked up in the SelectionChanged event. If flag set, I clear the DGV selection. This works because if a row was selected prior to sort, then SelectionChanged does not fire. It only fires if there was no selection, and that's when I want no selection to persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jimi I wound up with this soution - If click in header cell (for sort) flag sortClick is set by CellClick event. It is picked up in SelectionChanged event and if set will clear the DGV selection.

```
private void ArchersGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)                                                                               
{
   if (sortClick)                       
   {
       sortClick = false;
       ArchersGrid.ClearSelection(); // Clear any selection caused by sort (no row to select).
   }
   else            
   {
      // code for any other selection change              
   }                                
}        

private void ArchersGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.RowIndex == -1)
   {
      sortClick = true;
   }
   else
   {
      sortClick = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: If you just want to remove any selection, no matter what, when the grid is sorted, just subscribe to the `Sorted` event and add `ArchersGrid.ClearSelection();` in its handler

Comment: Thanks again Jimi for your comment. Actually in my application I don't want to unconditionally clear the selection after a sort.

[Case1] There is a selection prior to sorting. Sorting keeps that selection which is what I want. No fix necessary.

[Case2] There is no selection prior to sort. Sorting then causes a row to be selected. Not what I want.

In case1 SelectionChange event does not fire. In case2 it does fire. So in SelectionChange handler, if sortClick flag is set I just clear the erroneous selection.

Comment: The *answer* you have posted doesn't address these points, though. When you have a previous selection of rows (e.g., Rows with index 1, 2 and 3) and you sort the DGV, the Rows with the previous indexes are still selected, but these are not the same rows as before but the Rows that now occupy these *positions*. You need to store those references if you want to preserve the previous selection, as mentioned in my comment, and restore the selected Rows in the `Sorted` event

Comment: Jimi - sorry, I don't see the behavior you describe. I do have MultiSelect property set false so only one row may be selected at a time. I also tried MultiSelect true and I still don't see the issue.

Comment: Just a thought - the DGV is not bound to any data source, it is simply populated programmatically. Would that be the reason I'm not seeing the issue?